# illustrator 2017, pastes the copied text into the layer 1

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I am totally new to illustrator, so, Hello, good designers :)

My problem is, I have text, "Restore Purchases", just copied and had to paste it on a rectangle. I'm trying to make a button.

The text is pasted in layer 1, which I think it is the default layer, right?

While the layer I was working in was layer 38 I believe, what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not *quite* certain what your'e asking however....

Illustrator, by default, will paste onto the *highlighted* layer in the **Layers Panel**. If you wish to paste to a *specific* layer, highlight *that* layer in the Layers Panel *before* you paste. And make certain *nothing* is selected in the artwork.

If using **Paste in front/Paste in Back/Paste in Place** and you have an object *selected*, then Illustrator will perform the paste on the same layer as the *selected object*.

Also.. paste behavior, where layers are concerned, can be changed. In the **Layers Panel Menu** there's an option for **`Paste Remembers Layers`**...

[image]

If that is *checked*, then any paste command will paste the content back onto the *specific layer* it was copied from, or it will *create* a layer of the same name when pasting, if the original layer no longer exists.

Comment: Thank you, Scott. that's it, btw, I think practicing English would be a much better idea for, wouldn't it?  you kinda edited my whole question :D

Comment: Actually @Mohamad I didn't edit that much. I primarily added paragraph breaks so it was easier to read. I only changed one or two words. Your English is good `:)`

Comment: Thank You @Scott, I was just joking, I appreciate your help.